# How to build a language pack for endangered languages?

Tags: language-support, translation

I want to learn how to build language packs to preserve and advertise endangered languages. It can also be of great help for conlangers.

Comment: Great idea! Start your journey at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you talk about the Ubuntu specific language packs, it sounds to me like you are not updated on the purpose of those language packs.

The language packs are created by Canonical automatically for languages with a certain degree of translation coverage. We apply a 5% threshold.

You wouldn't preserve anything by creating language packs for more languages. Basically you would just spam the archive with not-so-useful language packs.

Note that the translations for poorly translated languages will not go away. They are there for the case that some individual or team want to improve the translation coverage of a certain language to the mentioned threshold, in which case language packs for that language will be created.

Comment: I see where you’re going with it, thanks anyway! I thought the packs were somehow compiled by netizens

Comment: @EvenHaffolett: If you elaborate on what you want to achieve, I might be still be able to guide you somehow.